# Como usar funções da AppCompatActivity dentro de um Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment, app-compat-v7

Tenho um fragment e preciso dentro dele de algumas funçoes do AppCompatActivity, como implemento os dois na mesma classe?

Está assim:

```
public class clientes extends Fragment {
```

Já tentei:

```
public class clientes extends Fragment implementes AppCompatActivity{
```

Ou vise versa.

caso não seja possível fazer, como eu faço essa verificação:

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
```

O getSystemService fica vermelho, e n dá pra usa-lo no fragment
Além disso, preciso usar o:

```
 @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = 
  act.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lista_curso_personalizada, 
  parent, false);
```

O getLayoutInflater() também fica em vermelho, mostra que não é possível usa-lo numa fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getSystemService` é um método de `Context`. `Activity` é um `Context`, por isso você pode usar chamar diretamente quando está dentro de uma `Activity`. `Fragment` não é um `Context`, então você precisa pegar um objeto `Context` e chamar o `getSystemService`. O jeito mais fácil é:

```
getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE).
```

Comment: vlw cara, muito obrigado